# Microsoft Office add-in javascript: search by matchPrefix:true- how to get the full word for the matched prefix

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to follow the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/search-option-guidance#search-based-on-a-prefix)

Also, adding the code here, since links can always move or get modified or go down.

```
    // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
    Word.run(function (context) {

    // Queue a command to search the document based on a prefix.
    var searchResults = context.document.body.search('pattern', {matchPrefix: true});

    // Queue a command to load the search results and get the font property values.
    context.load(searchResults, 'font');

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log('Found count: ' + searchResults.items.length);

        // Queue a set of commands to change the font for each found item.
        for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
            searchResults.items[i].font.color = 'purple';
            searchResults.items[i].font.highlightColor = '#FFFF00'; //Yellow
            searchResults.items[i].font.bold = true;
        }

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
        // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync();
    });  
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

It works fine, but I don't get the full word back. 
So, if the word is `patternABCDEFGH`, the matched word in `searchResults` by doing

```
var text = searchResults.items[i].text;
console.log('Matching text:' + text);
```

All I get back is `pattern`, how do I get the full word back ?

Comment: Have you tried matchWildcards option? Seems like you need  it. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `MatchPrefix` doesn't search every word that starts with that combination of letters - it searches only that combination of letters when it is at the beginning of a word. So it will only find the characters "pattern" in this case and not the entire "patternMatching" or "patternABCDEFGH".

As Juan mentioned, in order to get entire words that begin with a certain letter combination you need Word's variation of regex: wildcard search.

The wildcard pattern would look like this: [P,p]attern*>

This assumes you want both upper and lower case "p", followed by any character until the end of a word.

```
    var searchResults = context.document.body.search('[P,p]attern*>', {matchWildcards: true});
```